# How to change the number of decimal digits in arcmap in symbology

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, arcgis-10.3

I'm using ArcMap 10.3. In symbology, there are 6 decimal digits for the different classes of the variable I'm presenting. I'd like to show only 3 decimal digits. I can edit the label and change the decimals manually for each class. Is there any faster way to do this for all classes in ArcMap 10.3?[image]

Comment: See the Q&A [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169143/can-arcgis-automatically-round-labels-for-a-raster-symbolised-according-to-a-cla/169172#169172)  as there is a very simple way of doing this.

Comment: @Hornbydd, yeah, that's a bit easier! The linked one should probably be closed (merged) and you can post your answer here.

Comment: @Paul, I don't know, I liked your code that will be useful to others (including me) and it is a solution... Mine is just simpler! ;) Also what did you use to record that moving image?

Comment: @Hornbydd, I wrote a `.bat` file based off [this blog](http://blog.pkh.me/p/21-high-quality-gif-with-ffmpeg.html) (it's just a few calls to `ffmpeg`). Drag a video file onto it and choose start and/or ending times. You can use any recording software, but I'm using Snagit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can accomplish this with the `arcpy.mapping` module. The following should work as long as your symbology is [`GraduatedColorsSymbology`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/graduatedcolorssymbology-class.htm). Just paste into the python window and run the function with your layer name and number of decimal places. Since it's using Python's built-in `round()` function, you can even use negative numbers.

```py
def trunclabels(lyrname, n):

    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
    lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, lyrname, df)[0]         

    labels = lyr.symbology.classBreakLabels
    #split the labels, cast to float, round, then join back together
    lyr.symbology.classBreakLabels = ["{} - {}".format(*r)
                                      for r in [[round(float(f), n)
                                                 for f in lab.split(" - ")]
                                                for lab in labels]]

    arcpy.RefreshTOC()
    del mxd, df
```

[image]

Comment: do you know how to do this in ArcGIS Pro? When I try and use `trunclabels` I get the following error: `AttributeError: module 'arcpy.mp' has no attribute 'ListDataFrames'`

Comment: @MattA. Pro doesn't have the concept of data frames. You would instead list maps. See [here](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/migratingfrom10xarcpymapping.htm) for more info.