# Can ArcGIS automatically round labels for a raster symbolised according to a classification?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, labeling, symbology

I'm looking for a way to automatically adjust the reported precision of the label field for a float raster rendered in ArcGIS according to a classified symbology. Currently, the a classified raster symbology label is reported at the class break precision (8 decimal places).

I don't want to modify the class breaks itself, just round the reported break (e.g. to 2 decimal places) for producing a map layout.

I know I can modify the label manually but I don't want to have to do this for every class break and for multiple rasters.

Is there a setting automatically adjust the label?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the number of decimal places very easily by clicking on the Label header and choose Format Labels, then you can change the decimal place

[image: How to change decimal places]

Comment: What about for ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: @Nova yes quite possible in ArcPro too. Look [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/layer-properties/format-numbers-in-legend-labels.htm)/

Comment: that seems to only apply to feature layers, not rasters.

Comment: @Nova, you can change it, you just need to explore a little deeper. Try clicking on the Advance symbology Options...

Comment: It's for a classified raster symbology, and there really doesn't seem to be an option, no matter where I click!